# Create condition in a Trigger

Tags: mysql

I want to execute the trigger as long as my first condition is met. But it gives me an error when creating it

```
          DELIMITER $$
  CREATE TRIGGER `actualizar`
 AFTER UPDATE ON `detalle_ventas` 
 FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN
    IF NEW.estado = 'Cancelado' then
        UPDATE articulos SET stock += NEW.cantidad 
        WHERE articulos.id = NEW.idarticulo
        AND articulos.inventariable = 1;
    END IF;             
    END$$
 DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Triggers do not have a where clause.

Comment: Please add the error message you get and the mysql-version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to surrond the update with the IF clause if it is canceled

```
    DELIMITER $$
      CREATE TRIGGER `actualizar`
     AFTER UPDATE ON `detalle_ventas` 
     FOR EACH ROW 
        BEGIN
        IF NEW.estado = 'Cancelado' then
            UPDATE articulos SET stock = stock + NEW.cantidad 
            WHERE articulos.id = NEW.idarticulo
            AND articulos.inventariable = 1;
        END IF;             
        END$$
     DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: I have updated my question with your code. Only now how can I add the quantity to the stock?

Comment: but this query does this already,. for every article it adds quantity to the stock, so where is the problem?

Comment: I add the quantity of each record, not the actual stock

Comment: stock += New.cantidad

Comment: you increase the number of stock in articulos and increse by the number of the canceled row . So as far as i can see it does exacly that. can you please make a dbfiddle where you can show me the problem